# Updates break jquery modules

Tags: javascript, updating

I could need some help! (Newbie)
After updating a couple of modules on my local site, the jquery modules are behaving really weird or stopped working at all (Masonry, Chosen and Sidr). Masonry and Chosen don't work at all, Sidr just works on those pages where Masonry isn't on. Infinite Scroll stopped working, too and is replaced by the regular pagination. There are no error messages displayed or in the drupal report.
What should I do now?﻿
(the site is running Drupal 7.28 on Acquia Dev Desktop php 5.2.38)

Comment: Clear the cache first, if that doesn't fix it check your browser console; there are likely javascript errors in there

Comment: Did you find the solution? Was it any of the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

1. Caches may be stale. Clear and re-test. Even disable your JS aggregation/minify, then have Drupal regenerate the aggregated JS (after testing with it off to see if that fixed the issue).
2. If you also use the `jquery_update` module, you may need to update your jQuery library.
3. Sometimes replacing the modules with their DEV versions help fix the issue, because sometimes there's small bugs that get fixed in DEV first before a new stable update is tagged and released.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you updated `jQuery Update`, and it provided a version of jQuery UI that was too new for those modules. If you have `jQuery Update` installed, then try switching the versions of jQuery UI and see if one fixes them.

Also, clear all the caches whenever you switch.